# Cast interface to a class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, reflection, interface

I have a cms with a page that contains forms.

I want in the cms to have a dropdown with different class names that all implement a validation interface.

My form handlers contain a process method which I want to validate against the selected validation class.

So I have this interface:

```
public interface IEligibilityValidation
{
    bool IsValid();
}
```

and for example this class

```
public class ComplexEligibilityValidation : IEligibilityValidation
{
    public bool IsValid()
    {
        return true; /* complex logic here */
    }
}

public class SimpleEligibilityValidation : IEligibilityValidation
{
    public bool IsValid()
    {
        return true; /* less complex logic here */
    }
}
```

And then I have the form handler that can read the selected class name for the validation.

I am unsure whether my handler should implement IEligibilityValidation as well or whether I can somehow invoke the class using reflection.

For example:

```
public class SampleFormHandler : IEligibilityValidation
{
    public SimpleFormHandler(FormViewModel model, INode node)
    {
        this.model = model;
        this.node = node;

        eligiblityValidationClass = GetPropertyValue("eligibilityValidation");

    }

    public SampleProcessResult Process()
    {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eligiblityValidationClass))
            {
                var thisType = Type.GetType(eligiblityValidationClass);
                var thisInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(thisType);
                var isValid = ((IEligibilityValidation)thisInstance).IsValid();
                /* Works however, I need the IsValid to have access to a the FormHandler's properties and injected services */
            }

    }

    public bool IsValid()
    {
        /* Will Always be ignored */
        return true;
    }
}
```

What is the most elegant way for doing something like this?

The idea is that different FormHandlers will have a different Validation class assigned to them and when invoked the IsValid method will be able to use the properties of that form.

I am looking for some advanced architecture or something smarter than just require unnecessary code.

Thanks

Comment: Why you want to convert `SampleFormHandler` to `desiredType` to call `IsValid`, instead of simply call `this.IsValid`, I missing something?

Comment: this.IsValid would call the implementation of the current class.

I want to use the IsValid implementation of the class GUID I provide. So sometimes it will be SimpleEligibilityValidation, other times it will be ComplexEligibilityValidation or some other class that implements IEligibilityValidation.

You choose which validation should be used in the properties of the form.

Comment: For what I understand you want to create dinamically the validator object like `Activato.CreateInstance`, but the `IsValid`method how get the data to validate?

Comment: Yes but the tricky part is making it part of the handler so I can use the form's properties for the validation.

Comment: Look like you making some thing in a wrong way. may be it would be  better if you would share more details of place you are get in stuck. or idea of you want to realise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SampleFormHandler` shouldn't implement the interface. If I'm understanding your design correctly, you need to create an instance of the dynamically determined type, and then cast the object to the `IEligibilityValidation` interface.

```
public SampleProcessResult Process()
{
    if (eligiblityValidationClass != Guid.Empty)
    {
        Type validatorType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(eligiblityValidationClass);
        IEligibilityValidation validator;
        try
        {
            validator = Activator.CreateInstance(validatorType) as IEligibilityValidation;
        }
        catch (COMException)
        {
            // The class doesn't exist, or instance failed to be created
            // for some other reason.
        }

        if (validator == null)
        {
            // The class exists, but it doesn't implement the interface.
        }

        bool isValid = validator.IsValid();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is very close to what I have right now. I did remove the interface from the form handler as well. However, how do I get "IsValid" to work this the form handler's properties? Not sure how that would work without the need to pass a long list of parameters

Comment: I assume you're referring to the current values on the form? Sounds to me like you should be passing the ViewModel object, or some other object that contains the current properties, to the IsValid method on `IEligibilityValidation`.

Comment: Different validation classes will have different set of properties and services, therefore it can't be passed into the IsValid method

Comment: You could make the interface generic. Make it `IEligibilityValidation<T>`, with `bool IsValid(T input)`. It sounds like you might be over-architecting things a little, though. Do you really need an interface for this? Can't it just be defined on the form handler class, with something like an enum to choose between the different validation modes? It seems to me that the system you're describing would only really be necessary if you need to dynamically extend the list of validators at runtime.

Comment: I do need to extend the validators over time and I'm looking for an over-architected solution ;-)
For now I am passing the parameters and everything works fine, but in the long run I want to look into something more advanced.
I give the answer to you because it helped me the most. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you heard about cast (as, is)?
[Casting and Type Conversions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)

And you class SampleFormHandler hasn't implementation of IEligibilityValidation

anyway ((IEligibilityValidation)this).IsValid() you solution

UPDATE:

So you have to create instance of type that you want to execute IsValid on. So

```
var desiredInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(desiredType);
var validationDesired = desiredInstance as IEligibilityValidation;
if(validationDesired  != null){
validationDesired.IsValid();
}
```

Comment: It does, but I didn't add it in the sample. I added it now but as you can see it's useless.
The implementation will depend on the type of the selected class so the implementation within the class will always be ignored.
That's why I am looking for an elegant solution that perhaps won't require it.
What you suggest is what I am already doing and this you typed:  ((IEligibilityValidation)this).IsValid()  seems wrong to me

Comment: That's almost what I have already.
The problem is that the "IsValid" method of whichever validation class I use needs to have access to the form handler's properties and injected properties in order to perform the validation