# How do i convert a List<Interface> to List<Class> in c#

Tags: c#, oop, casting

I have an interface defined as

```
public interface IReaderInfo
{
    string Displayname {get;}
}
```

and a class that implements that interface

```
public class ReaderInfo : IReaderInfo
{
    string DisplayName {get;}
}
```

I then created a function which return List

```
public List<ReaderInfo> GetReaders
{
     var readers = new List<ReaderInfo>();
     var Ireaders = someobject.Getreaders();// Returns the list of IReaderInfo.
     // Now i would like cast Ireaders as readers and return.
}
```

How do i cast it?

Comment: If you need to cast `IReaderInfo` into `ReaderInfo` then why use interface

Comment: see this post: possible duplicate
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826607/cast-interface-to-a-class

Comment: What is the point of returning a list of concrete classes when you have interfaces? What are you going to do with objects that implement the interface but *aren't* `ReaderInfo` ? Why not return `List<IReaderInfo>` ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to create a new list with casted items:

```
var readers = Ireaders.Cast<ReaderInfo>().ToList();
```

Or, if there is a possibility to have incompatible IReaderInfo entries and you only want the actual ReaderInfo objects in the result:

```
var readers = Ireaders.OfType<ReaderInfo>().ToList();
```

Comment: Which will fail if the elements aren't *actually* `ReaderInfo` instances. Any class can implement this interface

Comment: @RaviKumarGN so what happens when you get an object that *isn't* ReaderInfo? What happens when you try to test this code using mock IReaderInfo objects? What if `GetReaders` *doesn't* return ReaderInfo objects at all? It explicitly tells you it *won't* return only ReaderInfo. Using `Cast` or `OfType` is breaking the API

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos wouldn't this be considered with the `OfType` suggestion? Its not my or your responsibility to decide, whether different actual types are to be expected and how to handle them - but I think with `Cast` (throw on different types) and `OfType` (filter on different types) the possibilities are mostly covered.

Comment: @grek40 there's nothing to decide. The method guarant explicitly states it will return objects that only have a specific interface. Anything else is an unsafe assumption

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thats only true for `someobject.Getreaders`, but `GetReaders` can have a different contract and it's just a matter of definition and documentation to specify what happens when the method is called and the data are different than expected.

Comment: @RaviKumarGN since you commented that it works for you, please consider accepting the answer. See [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 5):

The quick&very-dirty fix is to pass only  the objects that actually *are* ReaderInfo, by using [OfType<>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx). Using [Cast<>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) will fail if any of the objects implements `IReaderInfo` without actually *being* a ReaderInfo

```
var Ireaders = someobject.Getreaders();
var readers=Ireaders.OfType<ReaderInfo>().ToList();
return readers;
```

A better solution though would be to change the method's signature to return a `List<IReaderInfo>`, or the more abstract `IList<IReaderInfo>`. If `GetReaders` returns a list of interfaces it means it can return *any* object that implements the interface.

Why discard *some* of them? Why should `GetReaders` decide which objects to use and which to discard when all implement the same interface?

```
public IList<IReaderInfo> GetReaders
{
    var readers = new List<ReaderInfo>();
    var Ireaders = someobject.Getreaders();// Returns the list of IReaderInfo.
    return Ireaders;
}
```

For example, methods typically return interfaces when they *do* intend to return different types, eg mock objects, or handle multiple implementations. By returning `List<ReaderInfo>` you prevent your method from handling valid objects

**UPDATE**

*Versioning* is another very strong reason why one *shouldn't* cast interfaces to concrete types.

Googling for IReaderInfo I found a couple of pages that refer to RFID readers. A ReaderInfo returns the capabilities of a reader, but how do you expose *new* features for a new reader?

A common way to expose new features without breaking compatibility is to introduce a new class that implement the old interface `IReaderInfo` and place expose new features through a new interface, eg `IReaderInfo2`. Or the *existing* class can be extended with `IReaderInfo2`. A library can do that because clients are expected to work only through the interfaces, not directly against the concrete classes.

Comment: If clients are expected to work only through the interfaces, then why make the class public at all? Without a public class, the whole question of casting from interface to class would never occur to any user of the library.

Comment: @grek40 for the same reason a lot of methods in the BCL expose interfaces instead of concrete classes. Versioning is just one case. Testability is another - one of the BCL team's greatest regrets is hard-coding classes more than they should

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ:

```
Ireaders.Cast<ReaderInfo>().ToList();
```

Comment: `Ireaders.OfType<ReaderInfo>().Cast<ReaderInfo>().ToList()` should satisfy all comments.

Comment: Sometimes it is better to throw exception in Cast<> when you have unexpected item in source collection, than silently ignore it with OfType<>. It depends on context and requirements/specs, and author did not specify details, so my answer was only about casting.

Answer (score 0):

By using Linq

```
var derivedList = Ireaders.Cast<ReaderInfo>();
```

Comment: Which will throw if any of the objects implements the interface yet *isn't* an actual IReaderInfo

Comment: Throwing exceptions is not a good idea and *that's* what this code does