# C#: Upper cast - List<Interface> to List<Class> - cast obejct of internal class

Tags: c#, oop, c#-4.0

I have an interface defined as

```
public interface INamedReader
{
     string DisplayInfoLine { get; }
     string DisplayName { get; }
}
```

and a class which implements that interface but it is an internal class

```
internal class NamedReader : INamedReader, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public NamedReader();

        public string DisplayInfoLine { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public override string ToString();
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "");
        protected virtual bool Set<TField>(ref TField field, TField value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "");
    }
```

and a class which implements the above NamedReader class

```
internal class NamedReaderDevice : NamedReader
{
    public NamedReaderDevice();

    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

and now i defined class which implements INamedReader

```
public class ReaderDetails: INamedReader
{
     public string DisplayInfoLine { get; }

     public string DisplayName { get; }
}
```

I then created a function which return List.

```
public List<ReaderDetails> GetReaders
{
     var readers = new List<ReaderDetails>();
     var Ireaders = someobject.Getreaders();// Returns the list of NameReaderDevice (which is an internal class).
     // Now i would like cast Ireaders as readers and return.
}
```

can someone please help me out in this, that would be great.

Comment: Like `var Ireaders = someobject.Getreaders().Cast<INamedReader>();` using linq?

Comment: Like `var Ireaders = someobject.Getreaders().OfType<ReaderDetails>();` ?

Comment: if it's a list of 'NamedReaderDevice' you cannot cast them to 'ReaderDetails'

Comment: Didn't you just ask this already? `..GetReaders().OfType<ReaderDetails().Cast<ReaderDetails>().ToList()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i convert a List<Interface> to List<Class> in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44668956/how-do-i-convert-a-listinterface-to-listclass-in-c-sharp)

Comment: What do you mean with the type `Ireaders`? Would you like it to be `IList<INamedReader>` or `List<INamedReader>` or something else? Or does the list have to be a List<NameReaderDevice> (which is, as you say, internal?)

Comment: Ireaders is just variable Name.

Comment: My bad... I did not read it well. Still the question remains always the same: What type do you want it to be?

Comment: List<ReaderDetails> - list of ReaderDetails objects

Answer (score 0):

You are basically trying to **convert** one class into an entirely different one, like in this picture, trying to **convert** `Class2` to `Class3`:

[image]

In this scenario, even if they share an interface, you cannot **cast** between one and the other.

You have a few options:

1. use a method (extension or otherwise) to convert between classes, using [Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3673216/891715) or [serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38519023/891715) (not very efficient)
2. use a [conversion operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18784359/891715) (more details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09479473(v=VS.80).aspx))
3. return an interface instead of an explicitly implemented class in your `Getreaders()` method and then use an interface in your application instead of an explicitly implemented class;

In case of (3) if you need or want to further decouple your class implementation, then you may use dependency injection for it (eg. [SimpleInjector](https://simpleinjector.org/index.html), accessible through nuget). In that scenario you can for example create objects of said interface in code that does not have acces to the internal class implementing it,