# Return interface as data type

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have the following class:

```
public class EconomicKeyFigures : IEconomicKeyFigures
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public decimal Savings { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have the following method:

```
private static List<IEconomicKeyFigures> ToEconomicKeyFiguresData(this IEnumerable<EconomyKeyFiguresMock> data)
{
    return data.Select(x => new EconomicKeyFigures
    {
        Savings = x.Savings,
        Year = x.Year,
        InterestSensitivity = x.InterestSensitivity,
        EnergyCost = x.EnergyCost,
        Debt = x.Debt
    }).ToList();
}
```

This don't work, because I get the following error:
[image]

However, this code works like a charm:

```
private static IInsuranceInformation ToInsuranceInformationData(this InsuranceInformationMock data)
{

    var insuranceInformation =  new InsuranceInformation();
    insuranceInformation.HasBoardMemberLiabilityInsurance = data.HasBoardMemberLiabilityInsurance;
    insuranceInformation.InsuranceContractEndDate = data.InsuranceContractEndDate;
    insuranceInformation.InsuredBy = data.InsuredBy;
    insuranceInformation.IsApartmentInsuranceIncludedInInsuranceContract = data.IsApartmentInsuranceIncludedInInsuranceContract;

    return insuranceInformation;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: While `EconomicKeyFigures` and `IEconomicKeyFigures` have a ("is-a") relation, `List<EconomicKeyFigures>` and `List<IEconomicKeyFigures>` do not.

Comment: See also [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)

Comment: Post the exception text, not a screenshot of the exception. You can easily get it by clicking on the `Copy Details` link on the exception popup

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i convert a List<Interface> to List<Class> in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44668956/how-do-i-convert-a-listinterface-to-listclass-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it does not work with List is because while `EconomicKeyFigures` and `IEconomicKeyFigures` have a ("is-a") relation, `List<EconomicKeyFigures>` and `List<IEconomicKeyFigures>` do not.

You cannot just cast `List<EconomicKeyFigures>` to `List<IEconomicKeyFigures>` , but you can use Linq's [`Cast<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=netcore-3.1) like in this example below:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
    
    public static List<ISomeDataType> SomeFunction( List<ISomeOtherDataType> input )
    {
        //return input.Select( x => new SomeDataType() ).ToList(); // Doesn't work!
        // Linq's Cast<T> will cast every item and return IEnumerable<T>
        return input.Select( x => new SomeDataType() ).Cast<ISomeDataType>().ToList();
    }
}

public interface ISomeOtherDataType{}

public interface ISomeDataType{}

public class SomeDataType : ISomeDataType{}
```

(See Fiddle : https://dotnetfiddle.net/5gG1R7)

For further information see [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)

---

EDIT: After a little experiment, this seems to work equivalently:

```
return input.Select( x => new SomeDataType() ).ToList<ISomeDataType>();
```

(https://dotnetfiddle.net/j29cxr)

Tried on Framework 4.7.2 and Core 3.1

---

EDIT 2:

Credits to @mjwills's comment - yet another possibility:

**Replace `}).ToList();` with `} as IEconomicKeyFigures).ToList();`**

Comment: How about this: ToList<IEconomicKeyFigures>(); ?

Comment: It seems to work. I guess it's the same as .Cast<IDataTpe>()?

Comment: Oh, yes. Just tried it myself. Somehow I expected it to fail, but it doesn't. Hmm, interesting.

Comment: Sadly, that's not mentioned in the docs ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netcore-3.1